# Multiply one line in Assembly

Tags: assembly, multiplication

How can I do How to multiply one line in Assembly?

I need to do :

> 32*bx->bx

without the "multiply " and div commands.

Comment: You can use SHL to multiply by powers of 2. Shifting BX left by 5 would be the same as multiplying by 32. 2^5=32

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using register BX, my assumption is that it is x86 assembly.

In that case, you may want to use the "logical shift left" operation:

```
SHL bx,5
```

It will multiply by 2^val.
In this case: 2^5=32